# Performance Problems on SQL Server + .net C# Application

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle

I support an application that runs on SQL Server and was developed on .net c#. The application gets its information from the local system (ERP) and process it in a few batches during the day (most of the times, it'll be in just one batch). Then it presents it to the users in the form of charts and reports (the application is basically a reporting one; almost no data entry is made on it, but on the company’s local system).

In a couple of big companies where the application was implemented, as the amount of history started piling up in some important tables, the processing times started to grow largely, going from 30 minutes to 6 or 7 hours per batch process. Some other tasks in the software suffered performance decay as well.

The amount of processed records per day (in the batch processes) has stayed more or less the same (between 500.000 to 1’000.000 records per day, spread across several tables).

Is this something to be expected from a System running on SQL Server? Would using Oracle as the DB make this type of problems go away or at least diminish them? Or do you think that we should focuss on DB and application design instead, regardless of the DB used?

Comment: "Is this something to be expected from a System running on SQL Server?" No. "Would using Oracle as the DB make this type of problems go away or at least diminish them?" No.

Comment: SQL Server is built for this type of data structure. I'd be willing to put money that your .NET application is getting too much information without filtering clause. Use a profiler to figure out what type of queries you're running.

Comment: The first thing to focus on is finding out exactly *why* the process is running slowly; until you know that, you can't decide how to fix the problem and discussing 'solutions' is just speculation.

Comment: You need to figure out where the problem is first, then solve it.  Use a profiler to figure out where the bottlenecks are.  Tuning your db won't help much if your application code is the problem.  Likewise, re-architecting your application is a waste of time if your database design is bad.

Comment: This is just formulated different than [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198251/selecting-a-development-platform?noredirect=1#comment23166762_16198251) and as such is a question that can be debatable.

Comment: Thanks everybody and @Patrick for pointing me in the right direction to ask the question!!!

Comment: This is not a problem with the DBMS product (SQL Server), it is a problem with the database design and administration.  Fixing it means addressing the design and/or administration of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server and Oracle are both solid platforms for managing large amounts of data.  Switching the database platform is unlikely to solve your problem, and indeed may make things worse as you adapt your code to the new target DB.

You need to determine where exactly the performance bottlenecks are.  Tuning any SQL server is a non-trivial task.  If you can, have a DBA work on the issue.  If not, here are a few tips:

- Measure exactly where performance time is spent.  Re-create the large production systems and use a profiler if you can.  If not, add a logging mode that writes out key performance metrics (e.g. time fetching data, time processing data in C#) that you can turn on or off.
- Do a health check of the production SQL server using [sp_Blitz](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/)
- Use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor.  It finds many common issues including missing or poorly selected indices.  For detailed steps see http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Database+Engine+Tuning+Advisor/97860/
- Review the most expensive data operations to make sure you don't fetch more data than you actually need (no extra columns, and a WHERE clause that returns only the necessary rows).

Answer (score 1):

SQl Server can easily handle terrabytes of information. Likely the problem is that you don't have anyone available to you who actually knows how to design or maintain a large database. If you have no dba experienced in large systems, you need to hire one. You should have had a database specialist do the design. If you used an ORM, it could very well be contributing to the problem. The problem could also be in the indexing, in the sql code, in the table design in the network, in underpowered hardware, in out-of-date statistics, etc. You are in specialist territory and you need to hire or create a specialist. At a minimun you need to read several books on performance tuning from start to finish. There are many many things that can cause a system to perform badly under a production load.